# Why can't extensions with protocol conformances have a specific access level?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-extensions, access-levels

Assume we have the following example code:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func someFunction()
}

public class MyClass {

}

public extension MyClass: MyProtocol {
    func someFunction() {
        print("hello")
    }
}
```

Compiling the code above gives the following error:

> Error: 'public' modifier cannot be used with extensions that declare protocol conformances

The same thing occurs if I mark the extension as `private`. It seems as though you cannot set the access level of an extension that conforms to a protocol, regardless of what the access level is set to. Even setting the protocol declaration to `public` or `private` does not remove the error.

#### Question

What is the reasoning for Swift restricting an extension's access level in this way if it conforms to a protocol? If the protocol conformance is applied at the class level, there is no such restriction.

If I obey the compiler and remove the `private`/`public` designation, what is the access level of `someFunction()`?

```
extension MyClass: MyProtocol {
    func someFunction() {
        print("hello")
    }
}
```

I imagine in this case it would follow the original `MyClass` implementation and be `public` but I am not sure.

Is this behavior there because a protocol conformance in an extension means the entire class conforms to the protocol, and therefore it is redundant to re-specify the access level in the extension?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's because it's impossible to conform to a protocol at any access level other than the access level of the protocol itself. In other words, if you have a `public` protocol, you cannot have `private` conformance to it. This is partially because protocol conformance is something that can be queried for at runtime (and therefore cannot differ between what module you're in, or be implemented twice in different files/modules), and partially because it would just plain be weird if a type conformed to a protocol in one file and didn't conform to that protocol when used in other files.

As for your question of the access level of `someFunction`, it follows the same rules as any other function. Which is to say, it defaults to `internal`, unless the type itself has a lower access level. So in your case, if `MyClass` and `MyProtocol` are both `public`, you can expect to get a compiler error telling you that `someFunction()` needs to be marked `public` as well. But since it looks like `MyProtocol` is in fact `internal`, omitting any access modifier works as `someFunction()` defaults to `internal`.

Answer (score 5):

Private conformance might violate **Liskov Substitution Principle**

Quoting an abstract from apple devloper forum reply to a similar question:

"The biggest thing I've noted about private conformance, especially amonst classes that are meant to be subclassed further, is that you often end up with conflicting implementations."

For example, you have a class that privately conforms to a protocol and implements all of its methods. Later a subclass comes along and wants to do the same, but only wants to implement the required methods (because the optional ones not being implemented might provide some default behavior that subclass wants). But now you have 2 problems:

1) The object expecting this protocol implementation now has possibly 2 consumers of the protocol on the same object. This leads to both objects having to guard against unexpected calls. Or none, as due to the private conformance, the subclass can't call super to resolve the unexpected calls.

2) There is no way for the subclass to get the behavior it wants without modifying the protocol, as the superclass's implementation can't be removed without affecting its behavior either.

Source: [Link to Apple Developer forum thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13103)

Answer (score 1):

> If I obey the compiler and remove the private/public designation, what is the access level of `someFunction()?`

Whatever you say it is. Nothing stops you from marking the access level of `someFunction()`. But in this case you cannot mark it as `private`, because the access level of MyProtocol is `internal`.

The default, therefore, is `internal` in your code. Nothing is ever `public` by default; `public` is always an explicitly opt-in designation.

Comment: functions in public extensions are public by default :)